# Is there a proper term for sets of interdependant functions?

Tags: functions, terminology

I am looking for a term that would describe the sets of functions that are very closely related, such as:

- the trigonometric functions $\sin$ and $\cos$
- the hyperbolic functions $\sinh$ and $\cosh$
- etc (?)

By "very closely related" I mean that to evaluate one function of the set, one might evaluate one, more or all of the other functions in the set and then could *derive* the result thanks to some relation of interdependency.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would choose to look at this is that these functions are closely related since they *parametrise* some curve - and it is the parametrisation that gives the relationship between them.

For example. $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are related since they parametrically represent a point on the unit circle, $$(\cos x, \sin x), x \in [0, 2 \pi) \\x^2 + y^2 = 1 \ \ \text{(circle equation)}$$

Similary, $\cosh x$ and $\sinh x$ are parametric points of a hyperbola,

$$(\cosh x, \sinh x) \\
x^2 - y^2 = 1 \ \ \text{hyperbola equation}$$

One could argue that there are always parametrizations of any choice of functions, but the functions that you mentioned, which are the trignometric functions are very closely tied to the conics, hence are more "natural" parametrisations that many other choices.

Comment: But according to this definition any two functions are related; certainly this isn't what the OP had in mind?

Comment: I'd argue that you can always come up with silly parametrisations for something, but the functions that he mentioned (the trignometrics) are all intimately related to the parametrisation of the conics. Do you disagree with that?

Comment: This is interesting, but Alex Provost is right, I would like to find a term that works for all those families of functions. By "etc (?)" I meant that I do not know if there are less obvious examples in the set of compositions of elementary functions.